Can “cumbersome” be used for “watches”?

Working from home all the time, I find wearing a watch a bit cumbersome.

I searched for “cumbersome watches” but got very few hits. “Cumbersome” here I mean is “inconvenient and uncomfortable to wear”. If this word doesn’t fit this sense, is there any better alternative?

Maybe you should say pointless seeing as you can see the time on your computer. What do you want to say? That the watch is pointless, heavy to wear, uncomfortable?

Of course, cumbersome + noun is less frequent than: X Is cumbersome. Things are said to be cumbersrome. There is no such object as a "cumbersome watch". That would require specific context to be used like that. You need to post the definition of the word in your question.

Thanks @Lambie Maria-Lou A. I’ve edited my post to add the definition of the word that I want to use. Could you check that again?

It doesn't change my comment at all. How could it? I was just telling you to post a dictionary definition in the future at least to show you've done the work.

It's OK, although it does rather imply that the watch is large or heavy. What's wrong with 'inconvenient'?

@Phoebe There's no reason you can't use "cumbersome X", I don't find "X is cumbersome" to be more common or natural as Lambie suggests. For example, "Are you tired of heavy bracelets and cumbersome watches?" - I don't see a way to rephrase that easily. There's no need to devote an entire sentence to describing something as cumbersome, it can be used like any other adjective + noun - e.g., "He was uncomfortable wearing an ill-fitting suit and a cumbersome watch."

@NuclearHoagie That's exactly what I mean by context. And it goes for just about any [adjective] + [noun]. Sure, an uncomfortable watch can be that way because it is cumbersome. No problem. But saying you can't find a definition for "cumbersome watch" makes little sense. That was my point. Asking questions without any context is pretty pointless.

The dictionary gives two senses, neither of which fit well.  "Large and heavy, difficult to move or carry" - Few would find it hard to lift a watch, so this isn't quite right.  -- or -- "Slow, complicated and inefficient" but it seems unlikely that you have a much simpler way to tell the time. I suppose, if you have your computer or phone in your hand then that is as efficient as a watch.
What you probably mean is that you find the watch "uncomfortable"  Or switch your sentence and describe how not wearing a watch feels   Ob xkcd https://xkcd.com/1420/

There's also bulky.

The adjective phrase a bit cumbersome is object complement.  It describes the gerund-participial phrase wearing a watch rather than the watch.

cumbersome
in American English
(ˈkʌmbərsəm)
ADJECTIVE 1. burdensome; troublesome

Collins Dictionary

@Mari-Lou A, from the burdensome; troublesome in Collins,  I thought if the watch breaks down often, we could describe it as such.

okay, agreed.   thanks.  I will edit my answer.

This is a picture of a watch created by Jacob&Co called Astronomia Solar Zodiac. If someone said it was cumbersome, who would disagree?  Whether you love it or hate it, it's an amazing feat of engineering, craftsmanship  and design but it looks heavy, bulky and impractical to wear every day. For some it would be a cumbersome watch to wear.

Whereas, for many people in their 20s and 30s, a common reason for never wearing an ordinary watch is because it feels uncomfortable or annoying.
